# iPhone 5S gets very hot and drains battery

Tags: iphone, icloud, battery

My iPhone 5S is getting very hot and the battery drains like 5 % in 30 seconds. I've tried it all, restoring and stuff and I've read that the problem is with iCloud. So I've deleted my iCloud account from my iPhone and now it is cool.

But still I really need to use my iCloud.. Some say that you need to make a new iCloud email. But that doesn't seems to be a solution because I use that iCloud email with all my devices.

How can I find the problem in iCloud?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would connect to a fast WiFi and re-enable iCloud. The WiFi will drain the battery far less than the cellular modem for transferring 1 GB of data since it will finish much faster in most cases. Also, you might need to plug into power to let however much data you have sync.

Some big items you can turn off temporarily are:

- iCloud Photo Stream
- iCloud Backup
- Any other large users of data from the settings app, iCloud and settings app, usage

Another thing you could try is to disable all iCloud settings, and enable them one by one.

Once the device is caught up, you can test the device on LTE/3G data without the power cord and WiFi to see that the battery usage isn't due to downloading a lot of data from the cloud or putting that data up in the cloud.

Comment: Oke so I've tested it again with doing it one by one. I don't use Photo Stream/Backup so thats already off. 

I cannot use *Reminders* and *Find my iPhone* with those 2 the iPhone gets very hot and drains instantly.

Comment: Wow - you could edit that into my post and accept it or answer this yourself. Good sleuthing.

Comment: Another thing to check is to make sure the stopwatch isn't running.

Answer (score 0):

Might be the Apple Remote app. After the last update, I started having problems with phone staying hot and battery life draining rapidly. The Remote app had turned itself on to "stay connected". I think the phone was constantly trying to sync with my home computer. After shutting off the app, phone immediately started cooling off. Took three days to figure this out. Support wasn't helpful as all they could suggest was to do a new phone set up. NOT HELPFUL!

Answer (score 0):

I fixed this problem by deleting my iCloud account on my phone.  Then i set up a new rule in my mail so that any mail coming in to my iCloud account got automatically sent to another email account (which i have on my phone) this is a temporary fix until apple sorts this out. Its not ideal but it works for now..

Answer (score 0):

Turn blue tooth off. That should help.